# How to add two gemTypes using Amazon seller api in xml format

Tags: e-commerce, integration, amazonsellercentral

We are using Amazon seller api's to create listing of our products . Some of our products is having two type of stones in a single earring . So how to add two gemstone details in single product listing . Please share your thoughts or any sample xml file to add these details . Amazon xsd file is not helping us .
thanks !